# removeAll From a List Cause java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

I want to set successList as `[10,14]` What i tried is,

```
String oneStr = "10,11,12,14";
String twoStr = "11,14";

Returns r = new Returns();

r.setFailureList(Arrays.asList(twoStr.split(",")));
r.setSuccessList(Arrays.asList(oneStr.split(",")));

r.getSuccessList().removeAll(r.getFailureList());
System.out.println(r.getSuccessList());
```

The Returns Class is,

```
List<String> successList;
List<String> failureList;


public List<String> getSuccessList() {
    return successList;
}
public void setSuccessList(List<String> successList) {
    this.successList = successList;
}
public List<String> getFailureList() {
    return failureList;
}
public void setFailureList(List<String> failureList) {
    this.failureList = failureList;
}
public void setFailureList(ArrayList<String> failureList) {
    this.failureList = failureList;
}
```

And Cause  `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` the stackTrace is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could it be because the successlist you get is an unmodifiable list as mentioned here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram Oh. "answered by documentation in the obvious place". Removing my upvote. Still it's a well formulated question that doesn't deserve a downvote IMO.

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't do the downvote :)

Comment: @JanDvorak Is My Question is not in COrrect Format.. Why DownVote ???

Comment: @RakeshKR well, I didn't downvote. What makes you think I downvoted despite saying this didn't deserve a downvote? I only unupvoted, since this is answered in the documentation of the methods you're using, I don't think this will be a useful question (but I might be wrong about that)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From docs of [asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

So when you are directly modifying(adding, removing ..etc) to that, you end up with `exception`.

So , but in the case

```
   new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(twoStr.split(",")))
```

Here you are not referring to the `list` directly. You are creating a new `ArrayList` and using the data of the list returned by `Arrays.as.asList(twoStr.split(","))` ,which is not a `Unmodifiable`(in terms of size).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
r.setFailureList(Arrays.asList(twoStr.split(",")));
r.setSuccessList(Arrays.asList(oneStr.split(",")));
```

as

```
r.setFailureList(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(twoStr.split(","))));
r.setSuccessList(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(oneStr.split(","))));
```

Comment: What about `new ArrayList<String>(twoStr.split(","))`?